# Another solidity error Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I ran into this error after trying to destroy the contract with selfdestruct.

```
    function endSale() public{
    //require admin
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    //transfer remaining ast tokens to admin
    require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));
    //destroy contract
    selfdestruct(admin);
}
```

When I run truffle test this is the error i get

```
 Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
  at ABICoder.decodeParameters (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-eth-abi\src\index.js:226:1)
  at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:465:1)
  at Method.outputFormatter (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:818:1)
  at Method.formatOutput (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-eth-contract\~\web3-core-method\src\index.js:163:1)
  at sendTxCallback (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-eth-contract\~\web3-core-method\src\index.js:473:1)
  at C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-core-requestmanager\src\index.js:147:1
  at C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-provider\wrapper.js:112:1
  at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:96:1)
  at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
  at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:1)
  at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:1)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\W10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:47)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:406:35)
  at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1329:12)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Can someone help me, I tried to find the solution on the internet and nothing helped me?

Here is the test code

```
    it('ends token sale', function(){
    return AstTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance){
        //grab token instance first
        tokenSaleInstance = instance;
        return AstTokenSale.deployed();
    }).then(function(instance){
        //then grab token sale intsance
        tokenSaleInstance = intsance;
        //try to end sale from account other the admin
        return tokenSaleInstance.endSale( {from: buyer} );
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
        assert(error.message.indexOf('revert' >= 0, 'must be admin to end sale'));
        //end sale as admin
        return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: admin });
    }).then(function(receipt){
        return tokenInstance.balanceOf(admin);
    }).then(function(balance){
        assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 9999990, 'returns all unsold ast tokens to admin');
        //check that token price was reset when selfDestruct was called
        return tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
    }).then(function(price){
        assert.equal(price.toNumber(), 0, 'token price was reset');
    });
});
```

Comment: Share your deploy script of contracts

Answer (score 1):

So after searching for solutions on the internet, I fixed the problem. Because I was following a tutorial, I found out that the source code was changed, from destroying the contract to transferring the balance to the admin. Here is the solidity code for that

```
    function endSale() public{
    //require admin
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    //transfer remaining ast tokens to admin
    require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));
    //transfer the balance to the admin
    admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

And that led to changing test file to this

```
  it('ends token sale', function() {
return AstToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  // Grab token instance first
  tokenInstance = instance;
  return AstTokenSale.deployed();
}).then(function(instance) {
  // Then grab token sale instance
  tokenSaleInstance = instance;
  // Try to end sale from account other than the admin
  return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: buyer });
}).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
  assert(error.message.indexOf('revert' >= 0, 'must be admin to end sale'));
  // End sale as admin
  return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: admin });
}).then(function(receipt) {
  return tokenInstance.balanceOf(admin);
}).then(function(balance) {
  assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 9999990, 'returns all unsold ast tokens to admin');
  // Check that the contract has no balance
  balance = web3.eth.getBalance(tokenSaleInstance.address).then(balance =>{
    assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 0);
  });
});
```

});
});